# Client receiving two separate message as one with python socket

Tags: python, sockets

I define the server class as follows (**redacted**):

```
class server:
    def __init__( self, ip = "", port = 0 ):
        self.SetAddress( ip, port )
        self.__players = []

    def __SetSocket( self, blocking = 0, queue = 4 ):
        self.__listener = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
        self.__listener.bind( self.GetAddress() )
        self.__listener.setblocking( blocking )
        self.__listener.setsockopt( socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1 )
        self.__listener.listen( queue )
        self.__listener.settimeout( 5 )
        self.__read, self.__write, self.__error = [ self.__listener ], [], []

    def __AddClient( self, source ):
        c, a = source.accept()
        c.settimeout( 5 )
        self.__read.append( c )
        send( c, "Welcome!" )
        print a, "Connection established"
        return

    def __AddPlayer( self, source, nick ):
        if len( self.__players ) == 4:
            send( source, ('Error', "4 players already connected.") )
            self.__read.remove( source )
            return
        self.__players.append( nick )
        send( source, ('ID', self.__players.index(nick)) )

    def __RemovePlayer( self, source, gamer_id ):
        self.__players.pop( gamer_id )
        self.__read.remove( source )
        source.close()

    def __Connect( self ):
        joining = True
        while joining:
            r, w, x = select( self.__read, self.__write, self.__error, 0 )
            for s in r:
                if s is self.__listener:
                    self.__AddClient( s )
                else:
                    data = receive( s )
                    if data:
                        print data, s.getpeername()
                        if self.__MaintainPlayers( s, data ):
                            pass
            if len( self.__players ) == 4:
                joining = False
        return

    def __MaintainPlayers( self, source, data ):
        if data[0] == "Nick":
            self.__AddPlayer( source, data[1] )
            return True
        elif data[0] == "Quit":
            self.__RemovePlayer( source, data[1] )
            return True
        return False

    def run( self ):
        self.__SetSocket( 1, 4 )
        print "Waiting for players."
        self.__Connect()
```

where, the send and receive functions are as follows:

```
def send( channel, message ):
    try:
        channel.send( json.dumps(message) )
        return True
    except OSError as e:
        print e
        return False

def receive( channel, packet_size = 64 ):
    try:
        data = channel.recv( int(packet_size) )
        if not data:
            return None
        print data
        return json.loads( data.strip() )
    except OSError as e:
        print e
        return False
```

The `client` class is pretty simple (**redacted**):

```
class client:
    def __init__( self, name, srvIP, srvPort ):
        ip = socket.gethostbyname( socket.gethostname() )
        self.__server_address = self.__server_ip, self.__server_port = srvIP, srvPort
        self.__ID = None
        self.__nick = name
        self.__SetListener()

    def __SetListener( self ):
        self.__listener = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
        self.__listener.settimeout( 5 )
        try:
            self.__listener.connect( self.__server_address )
        except Exception, e:
            print "Unable to connect", e
            raise e
        print "Connected to %s:%d." % self.__server_address
        send( self.__listener, ("Nick", self.__nick) )

    def run( self ):
        self.__read, self.__write, self.__error = [ self.__listener ], [], []
        while True:
            r, w, x = select( self.__read, self.__write, self.__error, 0 )
            for f in r:
                if f is self.__listener:
                    data = receive( f )
                    if data:
                        print data
                        if data[0] == "ID":
                            self.__ID = int( data[1] )
                        # More conditions
```

What happens is, my client objects `receive` the `Welcome` and `ID` message simultaneously. This throws an exception as follows:

```
$ client.py
Connected to 10.109.1.92:7777.
"Welcome!"["ID", 0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "%PATH%\client.py", line 115, in <module>
    c.run()
  File "%PATH%\client.py", line 86, in run
    data = receive( f )
  File "%PATH%\connect.py", line 17, in receive
    return loads( data.strip() )
  File "%PYTHON%\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "%PYTHON%\lib\json\decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 28 - line 1 column 37 (char 27 - 36)
```

That is, the client receives the following as a single string:

> ```
> "Welcome!"["ID", 0]
> ```

which raises an error in `json.loads`.

Is there some method to introduce any sort of delay between the messages?

Comment: Currently in one of my chat application(using `Twisted`) I am using JSON to send messages, by JSON I mean something like `{'text': "Welcome"}`, `{"text": ["ID", 0]}` etc, this way it is easy to check whether currently the amount of data you've received can be parsed using `json.loads` or not. TCP has its limitation, so it may buffer the data or will break the data if it's huge.

Comment: Sometimes you'll get multiple messages merged together and sometimes you'll get only partial messages. In case of merged messages like `{'text': "Welcome"}{"text": ["ID", 0]}` you can split these easily(split at `}{`) and then parse each of them individually, this can get a little tricky when the message itself contains `}{`, if it is coming from user then convert it to base64 first before sending it over to socket, For partial messages you need to accumulate the data till you've something that you can parse. This is still easier than using a plain string with some delimiter.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary But I _am_ always sending `json` data. `json.dumps` in the `send` function.

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned you're not sending it in form of a dict: `json.dumps('Welcome!')` vs `json.dumps({'text': 'Welcome!'})`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I'm still receiving merged message: `{"text": "Welcome!"}{"ID": 0}`. From what I understand, now I'd have to split this at `}{`? How will the split messages be parsed?

Comment: You can do something like this for complete JSON strings: http://ideone.com/2R6qbs. For partial strings considering the messages itself will never contain  `}` , you can check  using`if currrent_accumulated_msg.endswith('}')` :...` .

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary The method worked. But I'd rather go with Andrew's answer below. Since, by using your solution; I'd still have to iterate over all the results in list later on. There's no such fuss by packing the data length with message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the size of the message when you send it so that when you receive it you can only return that message, and know that you have the whole message. There is nothing in the socket module to do this as they just implement a low level pipe.

When you send the message prefix it with the size of the message:

```
def send( channel, message ):
  try:
    msg = json.dumps(message)
    channel.send(struct.pack("i", len(msg)) + msg)
    return True
except OSError as e:
    print e
    return False
```

When you receive the message first retrieve the size, then repeatedly call `recv` until you have the whole message.

```
def receive( channel ):
    try:
        size = struct.unpack("i", channel.recv(struct.calcsize("i")))[0]
        data = ""
        while len(data) < size:
            msg = channel.recv(size - len(data))
            if not msg:
                return None
            data += msg.decode('utf-8')
        print data
        return json.loads( data.strip() )
    except OSError as e:
        print e
        return False
```

Comment: It does work wonderfully :). Although, `struct.unpack` [returns a tuple](http://devdocs.io/python2/library/struct#struct.unpack) which raises an error later for `size - len(data)`. Can be fixed by accessing `[0]` index. Thanks once again. Sorry for the nearly 2 weeks delay. I was having some semester exams.

Comment: Old, but gold :-).

Comment: What happens if in `channel.recv(struct.calcsize("i")` you also get only part of the data?

Comment: Good point - there is a bug in this code. The recv for the message size should be in a while loop to make sure you have the all four bytes.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, if you can guarantee your message won't contain a specific character (e.g. a null byte), you can append that to your string, and then server side, split the string on the null character:

Client:

```
socket.sendall(json_string + '\0')
```

Server:

```
recv_buffer = ""
while True:
    data = connection.recv(128)
    recv_buffer = recv_buffer + data
    strings = recv_buffer.split('\0')
    for s in strings[:-1]:
        print("Received: %s" % s)
    recv_buffer = strings[-1]
```

Comment: Interesting idea.